# Spring Boot throwing exception on invalid If-Modified-Since value

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

Sorry if this is the wrong place for this.

According the http spec as defined: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3

> A recipient MUST ignore the If-Modified-Since header field if the
> received field-value is not a valid HTTP-date, or if the request
> method is neither GET nor HEAD.

Spring Boot is not doing this. It is throwing an IllegalArgumentException that is not being handled by the code checking the header value.

Here is the conversion code in org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.java

```
/**
 * Return the value of the {@code If-Modified-Since} header.
 * <p>The date is returned as the number of milliseconds since
 * January 1, 1970 GMT. Returns -1 when the date is unknown.
 */
public long getIfModifiedSince() {
    return getFirstDate(IF_MODIFIED_SINCE);
}

/**
 * Parse the first header value for the given header name as a date,
 * return -1 if there is no value, or raise {@link IllegalArgumentException}
 * if the value cannot be parsed as a date.
 */
public long getFirstDate(String headerName) {
    String headerValue = getFirst(headerName);
    if (headerValue == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (String dateFormat : DATE_FORMATS) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(GMT);
        try {
            return simpleDateFormat.parse(headerValue).getTime();
        }
        catch (ParseException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse date value \"" + headerValue +
            "\" for \"" + headerName + "\" header");
}
```

So if you send the header If-Modified-Since:0 you will get an exception, instead of returning the fresh GET response as defined in the http spec.

Does anyone else see this as an issue?

Comment: The real question is what does a caller of this method do. The method itself cannot violate the spec.

Comment: While you are right - why would someone send an invalid If-Modified-Since header? I would rather fix the bug in the client, I'm afraid that the springframework wouldn't fix this issue immediately.

Comment: @zeroflagL - the caller doesn't handle it. Exception bubbles all the way up.

Comment: @burna - Yeah i fixed the call to send a valid date, just wanted to get other people's opinion on the subject, thanks.

Comment: This belongs in the Spring Framework issue tracker; please raise a bug on the spring framework project, component web. https://jira.spring.io

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this and recently [created a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14144) and [submitted a PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1029) to fix it In the meantime you might be able work around the issue using a filter to remove the header, e.g.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
            List<String> hdrs = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames())
                    .stream()
                    .filter(h -> !h.equals(IF_MODIFIED_SINCE))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return Collections.enumeration(hdrs);
        }
    };
    chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

encountered the same issue, using Spring - **4.2.5**.
upgraded to **4.2.6** -> issue solved.